# how to add a zero in the front of a number based on certain criteria while reading a csv file using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have csv file, one of the columns is:

```
acc_no

123456789345
646487620984
30985178903
20164850960
736473657466
```

I want to add a zero before these account no if the length of account no is 11 or not equal to 12

How can I do that while reading from the file using read_csv using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [423]: df['new_acc'] = df['acc_no'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>12}'.format(x))
```

**OR**

```
In [415]: df['new_acc'] = df['acc_no'].apply(str).str.zfill(12)
```

Output:

```
In [427]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[427]: 
         acc_no       new_acc
0  123456789345  123456789345
1  646487620984  646487620984
2   30985178903  030985178903
3   20164850960  020164850960
4  736473657466  736473657466
```

Answer (score 1):

the `str` accessor has access to most of Python's string methods.

we can use `zfill` to fill values to 12 characters.

```
df['acc_new'] = df['acc_no'].astype(str).str.zfill(12)

print(df)


         acc_no       acc_new
0  123456789345  123456789345
1  646487620984  646487620984
2   30985178903  030985178903
3   20164850960  020164850960
4  736473657466  736473657466
```